# How can I determine the max dimensions to use for an image I'm adding to my document?

Tags: graphics

I'd like to add a picture to my document. I'd like it to be as wide as possible without overflowing the margins. I have a few questions accordingly:

1. How can I calculate the number of pixels wide my document is, not counting the margins?
2. Is there a built-in command in LaTeX that will find this width for me?
3. If I wanted to calculate this width manually, what properties of the document and the image would I need to consider in my calculation?

An answer to 1) and 2) is enough for me, but it would also be helpful to know how to do 3) so that I can create an image beforehand that will fit into my document at its native size.

Comment: Just for a start: [Page layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: How large are the sheets of paper you print your document on? And, which font size do you use? Note that the margin width settings depend on whether you specify `10pt`, `11pt`, or `12pt` as a document class option.

Comment: The pixel count is only half the story. A pixel is not a fixed physical size, so how large a pixel graphic is when placed on a sheet of paper, depends on the, or how many pixels there is per inch. Try for example saving a 640x400 image from Gimp with two different resolutions and including both in a LaTeX document, you'll see they have different sizes.

Comment: You all bring up very good points. I'll edit my question when I have more time.

Comment: the number of pixels is ultimately a feature of the printer or system rendering the pdf file which will be different for different screens or printers using the same output from latex so it isn't really anything over which latex has any control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin pointed out in his answer, you can just use `width=\textwidth` to size a previously created image to the width of the text.

I think what your question is asking though, is at what dimensions should you create/export graphics such that they fill the text width *at native size*; that is, without using `width`, `height`, *etc*. options with `\includegraphics`.

As was pointed out in the comments, this depends on the desired dpi/ppi value. I will use 300 ppi (printing industry standard) for this example; you can adjust to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article} % adjust to suit
%\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry} % adjust to suit

\begin{document}
Hello, world! \showthe\textwidth
\end{document}
```

We can always get the current width of the text block (in `pt`) by using `\showthe\textwidth` in the document source, which will print to the log file:

> ```
> > 345.0pt.
> l.5 Hello, world! \showthe\textwidth
> ```

We can then do some unit conversions to obtain the correct width in pixels for a natively-included image:

> ```
> width_px = floor((345.0 pt)*(1 in / 72.27 pt)*(300 px / 1 in))
> width_px = floor(1432.129514 px)
> width_px = 1432 px
> ```

So, with the standard `article` class (`10pt` base font size and `letterpaper` default on my system), the text block is `345pt` wide, which corresponds to an image `1432px` wide at 300 ppi. The `floor()` is necessary in the calculation to give an integer pixel width without causing an overfull `\hbox` in the final output document.

Answer (score 1):

Ulimately, the maximum size is the size of the paper you are specifying, e.g. `letter` or `a4paper`. The dimensions of the paper is stored in the lengths `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`. If you want to limit the image to the size of the text block, you don't need any calculations as the text block is of size `\textwidth` times `\textheight`. Thus, you can insert an image using

```
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{image}%
```

Which will adjust if you change paper size or adjust the margins.